# CCLayer CCdirectorでエラー

Tags: objective-c, c++, cocos2d-x

`CCLayer`でエラーが出ます。

OSはMacBookAir、Cocos2d-xで動作させています。cocos2dでiAdの導入をしたくプログラミングをしています。

[こちらのサイト](http://tanukichi566.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-60.html)を参考に、試しに入力をしてみた結果以下の部分でエラーが出ました。何かフレームワークが足りていないとか、循環参照とか、色々とエラーの原因を検索してみたのですがうまくいきませんし、循環にもなっていないと思います。ちなみに拡張子はmmです。

ここからはソースになります。

ヘッダ部分

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "iAd/iAd.h"

@interface AdLayer : CCLayer //←この時点でエラー 
//内容はCannot find interface declaration for 'CCLayer',superclass of 'AdLayer';did you mean 'CALayer'?です。

+ (id)layer;

@end
```

ここから実装 AdLayer.m

```
#import "AdLayer.h"

@implementation AdLayer{
    ADBannerView* _adView;
}

+ (id)layer{
    return [[[self alloc] initLayer] autorelease];
}

- (id)initLayer {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:_adView]; //この時点でエラー
        // 内容はUse of undeclared identifier 'CCDirector',Did you mean 'CIDitector' ?です。
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc{
    [_adView removeFromSuperview];
    [_adView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Cocos2d-x 2.x系のコードを3.x系の環境でやろうとしてないか。互換性ないぞ

Comment: おっしゃる通り、ver3でやろうとしておりました。なるほど…やはりネットに掲載されているiAdの実装方法では情報が古く不可能なのですね。内容は大幅に変わってしまっているのでしょうか。書籍もiAd実装まで掲載してくれているものがなく、手詰まりです。